# Excel format from mm/dd/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to convert a date from a format with slashes to one with dashes. however when i try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3,"/","-")
```

It converts my the would-be date into a date integer. I have tried formatting it and it doesn't work on the expression. Does anyone know a way to do this? Preferably one that does not involve having to use VBA?

Comment: Does B3 contain a real date value or text? If your formula results in a number, then you can format the result as a date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply

```
=B3
```

and format the cell with `Custom` format `mm-dd-yyyy` (write this format in the `type` box of the custom format dialog).

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was missing something really obvious.